# How to make a list view to grow instead of scroll?

Tags: android, listview, header, scroll

I have a ListView, in which i have added a header. the header contains, another ListView. I want the ListView in the header to grow instead of scroll with limited size.

This I am inflating in the header

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/songinfo_geninfolist"
        android:isScrollContainer="false" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollbars="none" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
```

and this xml is for the main list

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/songinfo_linklist"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

but i am getting a list with header containing a list with a small height. i want the list in header to grow with the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your List to grow with its content, don't use a ListView. Use i.e. a LinearLayout and add the elements to that.

You can also try to give the upper ListView a fixed height (i.e. 100dip) and let the bottom ListView take the rest of the space.

Also you have to know that the layout_heigth parameter works differently in comparison other Widgets/Layouts. I.e. wrap_content does not make sense, because a ListView can display thousands of items and that would eat the whole memory.

If you want use ListViews you should have watched the google io session [world of listview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) by romain guy.

Comment: can i update the list height at runtime??
i need a list view because i want its items to get focused and get clicked.

Comment: thnks problem is solved. i set the height according to contents.